# How can one mutate a state when returning an empty action

Tags: haskell, action, monads, haskell-snap-framework

I have been learning haskell for some time and I just finished reading 'Learn you a Haskell for great good'. My question comes from an assignment I'm currently trying to complete. Basically, I have been using the Snap Framework and I'm currently having a hard time understanding how the state (in this case the Request + Response object, the MonadSnap) is mutated when making calls such the one below:

```
modifyResponse :: MonadSnap m => (Response -> Response) -> m ()
```

I can't quite figure out how the [modifyResponse](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/snap-core-1.0.3.0/docs/Snap-Core.html#v:modifyResponse) method mutates the underlying `MonadSnap` while only specifying it as a type constraint.

I've come across this similar concept while searching for the answer and I believe the same answer would apply if I wanted to keep a state and make the below functions work as intended, like the OP proposed in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7840126/why-monads-how-does-it-resolve-side-effects):

```
instance M Monad where ...

-- Modify the counter and do not produce any result:
incrementCounter :: M ()
decrementCounter :: M ()

-- Get the current value of the counter
readCounter :: M Integer
```

Comment: What does it mean to "mutate the MonadSnap"? Mutable values can be mutated, whereas `MonadSnap` is a typeclass, which is not even a value. `modifyResponse` modifies the Response - it does so by calling a function which modifies the entire `SnapState`, and modifies only the portion of the state corresponding to the `Response`.

Comment: I don't think I phrased that correctly. My question is how can I mutate the underlying SnapState which is itself contained inside the Snap record without even receiving it as a parameter. I got carried away by saying MonadSnap because it was the only thing that I could see in the declaration that was not so clear to me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the [source code](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/snap-core-1.0.3.0/docs/src/Snap-Internal-Core.html#modifyResponse) for `modifyResponse`:

```
modifyResponse :: MonadSnap m => (Response -> Response) -> m ()
modifyResponse f = liftSnap $
     smodify $ \ss -> ss { _snapResponse = f $ _snapResponse ss }
```

The only function in the `MonadSnap` typeclass is [`liftSnap`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/snap-core-1.0.3.0/docs/Snap-Core.html#v:liftSnap), and the only pre-defined instance of the typeclass is the [`Snap`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/snap-core-1.0.3.0/docs/src/Snap-Internal-Core.html#line-403) monad (where it's defined as `liftSnap = id`).

It's just a tiny bit of indirection in order to allow the function to work with other types that implement `MonadSnap` also. It makes working with [Monad Transformer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monad_transformer) stacks much easier. The signature could have been:

```
modifyResponse :: (Response -> Response) -> Snap ()
```

---

Now, perhaps your next question is: **"How does `smodify` work?"**

Here's the [source code](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/snap-core-1.0.3.0/docs/src/Snap-Internal-Core.html#smodify):

```
smodify :: (SnapState -> SnapState) -> Snap ()
smodify f = Snap $ \sk _ st -> sk () (f st)
```

As you can see, it's not magic, just functions. The internal `SnapState` is being hidden from you, because you don't need to know the internals of `Snap` in order to use it. Just like how you don't need to know the internals of the `IO` monad in order to use it.

Comment: Your answer about the indirection was especially enlightening. Another reference that actually helped me visualize what I was trying to understand comes from this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39807736/how-can-i-write-this-simple-code-using-the-state-monad?rq=1. The same way as `modifyResponse` does, the `addToState` acts upon the state without actually receiving it as a parameter. I guess that is a pattern I should get accustomed to.

Answer (score 1):

Every instance of `MonadSnap` must provide a [`liftSnap`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/snap-core-1.0.3.0/docs/src/Snap-Internal-Core.html#liftSnap) method:

> ```
> -- | 'MonadSnap' is a type class, analogous to 'MonadIO' for 'IO', that makes it
> -- easy to wrap 'Snap' inside monad transformers.
> class (Monad m, MonadIO m, MonadBaseControl IO m, MonadPlus m, Functor m,
>        Applicative m, Alternative m) => MonadSnap m where
>   -- | Lift a computation from the 'Snap' monad.
>   liftSnap :: Snap a -> m a
> ```

The means that any time there's a `MonadSnap m` it's easy to convert a concrete `Snap a` into `m a` via `liftSnap`.

Modifying a concrete [`Snap`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/snap-core-1.0.3.0/docs/src/Snap-Internal-Core.html#Snap)'s state [is done](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/snap-core-1.0.3.0/docs/src/Snap-Internal-Core.html#smodify) by succeeding with the new [`SnapState`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/snap-core-1.0.3.0/docs/src/Snap-Internal-Core.html#SnapState) and a unit `()` value. `sk` is the success continuation for what to do on success.

> ```
> -- | Local Snap monad version of 'modify'.
> smodify :: (SnapState -> SnapState) -> Snap ()
> smodify f = Snap $ \sk _ st -> sk () (f st)
> {-# INLINE smodify #-}
> ```

[`modifyResponse`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/snap-core-1.0.3.0/docs/src/Snap-Internal-Core.html#modifyResponse) lifts `smodify` from `Snap a` to `MonadSnap m => m a`. The function `f` passed to `smodify` is a function that modifies only the `_snapResponse` field of the `SnapState` record.

> ```
> modifyResponse :: MonadSnap m => (Response -> Response) -> m ()
> modifyResponse f = liftSnap $
>      smodify $ \ss -> ss { _snapResponse = f $ _snapResponse ss }
> {-# INLINE modifyResponse #-}
> ```